# Dealing with View Models and DBContext with complex, pregenerated data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

This is a question of best practices, I think.

While trying to learn MVC, I find myself working on a Create action for a particular entity in EF Core. I am trying to keep the Models empty of behavior, since that seems to be the best practice - putting all of the behavior for the Model into its Controller, letting the Model just handle data.

For the most part, this has been very easy and intuitive. However, I am now working on an entity that does something unusual: it generates a large amount of child data when it is first created. Here is what I have so far, which works fine:

(For context, this is part of a procedural game data generator. The top level entity is a Site, which has multiple Locations, each of which has multiple Areas. When the Site is created, I want to generate the children from random tables I've coded.)

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(Site site)
{
    // get id values for child creation, 
    // since they won't get auto-assigned until SaveChanges()
    int nextsiteid = _context.Sites.Count() + 1;
    int maxlocationid = _context.Locations.Count();

    // add site
    _context.Sites.Add(site);
    // add location children
    for (int il = 0; il < site.LocationCount; il++)
    {
        int nextlocationid = maxlocationid + il + 1;
        // constructor gets some site properties which influence
        // random values
        Location l = new Location(nextsiteid, site.Region, site.Faction);
        _context.Locations.Add(l);
        // add area grand-children
        for (int ia = 0; ia < l.AreaCount; ia++)
        {
            Area a = new Area(nextlocationid, site.Region, site.Faction, l.Terrain);
            _context.Areas.Add(a);
        }
    }
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Details", new { site.Id });
}
```

The controller Create action is already getting quite complex, and I'm nowhere near done generating the children. In addition to Areas, each Location will also need a list of child Transitions, each of which will have more child entities. Also, each Area is going to have multiple children (traps, tricks, monsters, treasure).

So my question is, at what point is it too much data for the Controller to be expected to handle? Does it make sense at some point to pass the DbContext into a method on the Model and let the model handle its own child creation? Adding all of the children that I want generated transactionally when the Site is first created is going to produce an incomprehensibly dense tangle of loops, and feels like it is violating some of the basic organizational principles of OOP. So I'm curious if there's a pattern or best practice that resolves this for MVC.

**Edit:** Modified example code to illustrate the fact that the child constructors may have more than just default values, and will likely need to analyze parent property values to know how to generate themselves.

Comment: it seems to me that what your controller is basically  creating Site/Area/Location objects with some default values. I would move this logic into the Site/Area/Location constructors respectively. Moreover, i wouldn't use the context directly into the controller. If i could choose, i would create a Site  repository and manage the AddLocation/AddArea methods. The repository would use the context, while the controller would use the repository. (https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36287.repository-pattern-in-asp-net-core.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Moving all initialization to the Model constructor is easily done, but doesn't quite address my question. I'm more curious about where the _context.Models.Add(model) calls should go. The generation of the randomized child data seems like application logic. That seems unusual to put into a repository. Also, it is worth noting that the child objects won't necessarily have only default values - some may have values that depend on parent values, which would have to be passed into the constructor as well, and analyzed by the Model constructor.

Comment: again, i would use repositories for all the operations involving the context.
you can move your logic into a service, and then inject both service and repository into your controller. your service methods will then give you back all the objects that you want to add to your repository

Comment: The repository pattern, while likely good advice, doesn't seem to address my concerns. My question stands whether I use a repository or a dbcontext in my controller. The service you mentioned, however, which moves the complex logic of child creation outside of the controller, but not into the model, does sound promising. Unfortunately, "service methods that give a list of all objects I add to the repository" (or context, for that matter) is a bit vague. Wouldn't the same complexity remain, just living somewhere else? My hope is to reduce child creation complexity, not just move it.

Comment: Sorry, your question is "at what point is it too much data for the Controller to be expected to handle?", and my suggestion was to "move" this complexity somewhere else (either into the model or into the service). I don't know much about reducing the child creation complexity because i don't have the sufficient insight into the logic of your application. hope it helped

Comment: Definitely! And I appreciate the advice!